# Full installation of Debian onto a USB stick

Tags: debian, debian-installer

Is it possible to boot the Debian installation medium and then install Debian onto a USB stick instead of to a harddrive? Or even better, is there a way to `dd` a full Debian installation directly to a USB stick?

Comment: I havent tried yet with usb to usb, just tried an installation of Debian but was taking too long and I got old hardware, what I tried is Debian, Fedora, openSuse installed on an external HD connected thru usb to the PC (each time one OS installed on the HD), the OS are totally unstable and can't be used.

Comment: Any PC from the last 18 years (64 bit) that has one CPU core and at least 2GB (for heavy desktops like Gnome, Cinnamon and KDE) of RAM isn't going to cause any instabilities for basic uses, let aside manstream modern web browsing which are huge CPU and RAM hogs since six years now. Even on such PCs, Debian installations should take around 30 minutes. About the instabilities, look for my comment on berndbausch's answer down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible and quite simple to achieve. It's basically the way you run a raspberry pi (though they typically use an sd rather than usb).

You will (most likely) need two usb sticks: one to flash the install image, the other to install onto as you want.

The process is pretty simple, flash the install image onto a USB drive.    I believe in windows you can now just right click "burn disk image".  Note you are not trying to create a live usb at this step.

Then, in this order

- boot from the install usb.  You will see a menu with a option to "Install Debian".
- Plug in your other usb
- Select "install Debian" and press enter

Then you just select your USB as the disk to install to.  **Be very careful not to install the boot loader to your hard drive**.  Usually there's a drop down at the bottom of your screen while choosing partition layout.

Comment: I installed Debian using the live installer, live installer now  comes with Calamares installer.

Comment: About the boot loader, with the Debian text mode installer I'm pretty sure that it doesn't ask and installs GRUB onto the main hard drive

Comment: @golimar these things change from time to time but I can't believe it gives you no option. At the very least, I can't believe they've completely removed the option to select your own partitioning which would let you put everything on the USB stick.

Comment: @PhilipCouling The partitioning menu is there of course, but the boot loader install comes later near the end

Answer (score 1):

I once installed and ran Centos on a thumbdrive. Since the drive looks like a normal SCSI storage device, it can be done without problems. In my case, however, the drive soon suffered from filesystem corruption. My verdict is, therefore, that it is probably not a good idea. Thumbdrives are not designed for long stretches of continuous operation. I would guess the cheaper the worst.

On the other hand, my SD-card-based Odroid has been running without a hitch for two years.

To improve longevity, limit writes to the drive. For example, don't use it as swap space and move very active directories like /tmp to separate filesystems.

Comment: Do you know what the cause of the corruption was. Intrinsically there's nothing about running a non-live version that should cause this but I'm curious.  It is after all the default way a raspberry pie runs (from dd)

Comment: Perhaps SD-cards are different, or this particular drive was just bad. My guess was frequent writes, but in truth I don't know where the corruption came from. After replacing the thumbdrive with an old laptop disk, there were no problems anymore.

Comment: I just went thru 2 days installing operating systems. I installed Fedora (30 and 33), Debian, Opensuse on an external HD (each time one OS) with an usb key installer. All OS crash, impossible to use, they can be installed, you can start using them but they are totally unstable. After this I wanted to install Windows 10 pro to see...but it's not possible, the Windows installer does not allow installation on usb connected devices.

Comment: Same. For some reasons simply installing Linux distros on USB drives (HDDs, SSDs, USB Keys, SDs, etc) as you would do on PC won't do it while running them live or installing them to Raspberry Pi SDs, etc works 100% as long as it is not on some very cheap USB drives with questionable flash cells. It's always the same issues: sometimes you can't boot anymore, or there's some corruption-like errors (softwares not starting, etc) while its not.  But why ? I however long ago sucessfully installed a distro on a SATA drive, then used it as USB (adapter) and things still worked but haven't tried since.